# Какие есть готовые парсеры кода Delphi?

Tags: delphi, парсер, поиск-библиотек

Так, чтобы на вход подавался какой-то модуль в виде текста, а на выходе был набор разных array с классами и их процедурами, аргументами, типами данных и т.п. в виде строки.

Какие есть готовые решения?

Comment: Например, вот - https://github.com/Fr0sT-Brutal/awesome-pascal#language